# Grafana UI shows "Grafana has failed to load its application files" from browser when users try to access

Tags: grafana, podman, rhel8

We are piloting Grafana in our work environment to see how it works, as we have no continuously monitoring tools at this time.

Right now we are monitoring two physical servers.  I'm running Grafana from my workstation and can access the UI with no issues.  If other users on the same network try to access it, they get a UI error.

I'm currently running Grafana with Prometheus and Prometheus Node Exporter containers from RHEL 8 workstation with Podman v3.4.2.  At this time, we are not using a Reverse Proxy.

I've sent the URL for the Grafana Web UI (all of us are using RHEL8 with Firefox), other users are getting the following when trying to acceess:

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

```
1.  This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings

2.  If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath. If not using a reverse proxy make sure to set serve_frmo_sub_path to true.

3.  If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build

4.  Sometimes restarting grafana-serve can help

5.  Check if you are using a non-supported browser.  For more information, refer to the list of supported browsers.
```

This is the command I used to launch the Grafana container:

```
sudo podman run -dit --name grafana --net podman -p 3000:3000 --privileged
-v /etc/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini:Z
-v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana:Z
docker.io/grafana/grafana:latest
```

These are the changes I've made to /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

```
domain = FQDN (of the workstation I’m working from daily)

serve_from_sub_path = true
```

Restarted the container and same results as before.

To test, I've downloaded an httpd image (Apache), launched a container from my workstation, and from a remote workstation, able to access the Test Page successfully.  So I know I can reach web content being served up from my Workstation remotely.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to fix. Had to upgrade Firefox, as it was running an older version, once we upgraded to the latest and greatest, we were able to reach the Grafana UI.